# Animate a rectangle's height to go up, not down

Tags: javascript, svg, snap.svg

I'm pretty new to snap.svg. I have a bar graph with rectangle elements that grow vertically. I'm having trouble animating them to go from 0 height to something like 200. They all animate from the top down. I need them to go from the bottom up.

This is my js..

```js
var s = Snap(".performance_chart");

Snap.load("images/performance.svg", function(f) {

  bar1 = f.select(".bar1").animate({height:202.43}, 1000, mina.linear);

  s.append(f);

});
```

And these are a few examples of the `<rect>` bars on the chart. The first `<rect>` is set to `height=0` so I can animate it starting from 0.

```
<rect class="bar bar1" x="108.3" y="246.08" width="55.21" height="0"/>
<rect class="bar bar2" x="252.89" y="251.52" width="55.21" height="77.67"/>
<rect class="bar bar3" x="308.09" y="112.25" width="55.21" height="216.93"/>
<rect class="bar bar4" x="395.5" y="237.85" width="55.21" height="91.34"/>
```

I've read things about needing to flip the y axis using a `transform` attribute but nothing I've done seems to work the way I need it to.

Comment: animate the y at the same time as the height.

Comment: I'm not familiar to the snap.svg library, but in "regular svg", the `x` and `y` attributes define the _top left_ corner of your rectangle. So if you want the height to decrease, you'll have to increase y by the same value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `x` and `y` attributes represent the *top left* corner of your rectangle. Decrease the top position by the same value as the height increases:

```
bar1 = f.select(".bar1")
  .animate({
     height:202.43,
     y: 246.08 - 202.43
  }, 1000, mina.linear);
```

`height + y` needs to remain equal in order for the bar to keep its position. Here's an example:

```html
<div style="display: inline-block; background: #eee;">
  <h2>Start</h2>
  <svg height="50" width="50" viewBox="0 0 100 100">
    <rect width="10" height="30" x="45" y="70"></rect>
  </svg>
</div>

<div style="display: inline-block">
  <h2>End</h2>
  <svg height="50" width="50" viewBox="0 0 100 100">
    <rect width="10" height="70" x="45" y="30"></rect>
  </svg>
</div>
```

Comment: Ok, so that's kind of close. They all grow from the bottom up but the bottom of the bar is not where it needs to be. Each bar is off of the bottom the same as its height. For example if my bar animates to 100 tall, its also 100 above where it should be located.

Comment: I think I got it figured out now. The animation of y should be 329.19 - the height. 329.19 is the location of the bottom of the chart.

Comment: The `height + y` before needs to be equal to the `height + y` after. I've included an example in the answer as well. Glad to hear you figured it out.